# Makefile mysteries: What is wrong with this particular use of pathsubst?

Tags: makefile

My makefile contains these snippets (among others):

```
SRC = src
OBJ = obj

DEPS = $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.cpp)

# ...

all : $(BINARIES)
    @echo $(pathsubst $(SRC)/%.cpp,$(OBJ)/%.d,$(DEPS))
    @echo $(DEPS:$(SRC)/%.cpp=$(OBJ)/%.d)
```

When I `make all`, only the second `@echo` outputs something:

```
$ make all 

obj/sample1.d obj/sample1_U.d
```

The (gnu make) [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs) states:

> Another type of substitution reference lets you use the full power of the patsubst function. It has the same form ‘$(var:a=b)’ described above, except that now a must contain a single ‘%’ character. This case is equivalent to ‘$(patsubst a,b,$(var))’

From this explanation, I would expect that both `@echo` statements produce the same output, which they clearly don't. What is wrong with the first form using the explicit `pathsubst`?

(I am using `gnu make 3.81` on OS X.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably you want `patsubst`, not `pathsubst`.

Comment: 4 minutes to go until I am allowed to click accept. What do you think, should I use them to harass Joel about idiotic rules like minimum character limits or minimum time until I may accept an answer or other bs?